# Does autotrace save the plan in plan_table all the time in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, oracle12c, database-administration

Does the autotrace executions save the execution plan of the query in the plan_table in all cases? Or is there any way that it stores the plan in v$sql_plan view and bypass the plan_table?